# Database transaction combined with REST call

Tags: java, database, spring, rest, transactions

I have to save records to a database and then send some data to a restful web service. I need them to happen together. If one fails then the other should not happen as well. So for example, consider the following code:

```
saveRecords(records);
sendToRestService(records);
```

If saveRecords fails with a database constraint violation then I don't want the rest call to happen. I could make saveRecords happen in it's own transaction and commit it before the call to sendToRestService but there is still the potential for the rest service to be down. I could keep up with whether the rest service succeeds and if it doesn't then try to send them later. I was just wondering if there is a better strategy since this seems like it would be a common scenario.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try Observer design pattern?

I'm assuming saveRecords(records) and sendToRestService(records) methods are in two different classes.

If you use Observer design pattern, you can notify the class containing sendToRestService() method in case if the calling class object changes.

Ref: [Observer Design Pattern](http://www.newthinktank.com/2012/08/observer-design-pattern-tutorial/)